# Limited with JavaScript onCLick() when making AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

I am working on an existing project and heavily using `jQuery` `AJAX` calls. Existing pages have three different sections header, left menu and main content. Implemented with `Spring MVC` it is updating whole page whenever view is returned from Spring controller.

Now since I am working with one of the menu item but having tab content I am using `jQuery` to manipulate data within tabs using `jQuery`. While doing so whenever I have to work with hyperlink I can't use `<a>` tag since return from link will replace whole page . So I am always limited to use `onClick()` even ton the link and do `AJAX` call then put response back in window using `jQuery`.

```
<a href="" onClick="return loadDetail()">Details</a>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: ...,
    url: ...,
    success: function(response) {
      $('#tab1-content').empty().html(response);
    }
  });
</script>
```

So my question is - Is there any other way so that I can use `href` properties of `<a>` tag and update window with response view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly. Could you try something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Details</a>
<script>
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        loadDetail(href);
    });

    function loadDetail(url) {
        alert("Load from: " + url);

        // Ajax call
    }
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7ef9pm2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent default behaviour of  tag just return false from your function.
See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s8mpwokt/

Or just like in Michael answer attach event from javascript so you'll get event instance in your callback function with `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.